# How to solve $y=x|4-x|$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is the solve routine for $y=x|4-x|$?

I want to express $x$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: Two cases, $x<4$ and $x\ge4$.

Comment: Function isn't injective. We have a $0$ at $x=4$ and around four it's strictly positive.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Rather five cases (for $y$): $(-\infty,0)$, $\{0\}$, $(0,4)$, $\{4\}$, $(4,\infty)$.

Comment: I mean to get rid of $|4-x|$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two cases:

Case 1:  $x > 4$ so $|4 -x| = x - 4$

So $y = x(x-4)$ so $x^2 - 4x - y = 0$.

Case 2: $x \le 4$ so $|4 - x| = 4 -x $

So $y = x(4-x)$ so $x^2 - 4x + y = 0$

Solve for $x$.  What do you get?